# integrate frontend app in backend resources

Tags: spring-boot, backend, frontend-maven-plugin

i have a web application with a springboot backend and a vuejs frontend.
i will deploy soon on a linux VM and i'm asking about the better way to do that :
option 1 : two seperate deployments. the backend as a springboot jar with embedded tomcat. very simple,and install a nginx for the front, and deploy my frontend sources
option 2 : integrate frontend sources in the target backend (with maven resources plugin), and deploy just a jar (no nginx, just the embedded tomcat)
it seem to be more simple like that but i don't know if it's a good practice

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thymeleaf for Spring Boot: https://www.thymeleaf.org/